# DHIS2 - android capture app connection error

Tags: dhis-2

I have config a DHIS2 server and i tried to connect them to tha android capture app but it's not work. And there is no error message.

I created a user with [this](https://docs.dhis2.org/en/implement/android-implementation/dhis2-configuration-for-android.html#implementation_guide_dhis2_config_creating_user_user)  documentation but nothing.

what should I do to solve this problem ?